# php sqlite query error with multi INSERT

Tags: sqlite

I'm having trouble with a query with sqlite.
It keep giving me :

> Warning: SQLiteDatabase::queryExec() [sqlitedatabase.queryexec]: near ",": syntax error in`

I dont 't understand because when i try my full query in `phpMyAdmin` it tells me it's alright but when I execut it with `$database->queryExec($sql);` it give me this error.

Here is the begenning of the query :

> INSERT INTO videos (src,videoid,title_url,title) VALUES ('youtube','m7v9427AjpM','cestmoiladmin','Petit kiff personnel :p')

Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean this is the "beginning of the query"? Is there more? Can you post a little extra?

Comment: oops i've sent the message... And it goes for 50 insertions. It seems that the error is at the begenning. I tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) but could not make it work.

Comment: The simple answer @user is that you're using MySQL syntax in a SQLite database. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Comment: I know but i thought it had the same syntax. I guess with your message i'm wrong.

Comment: Ok it's all edited back to the exemple in the link. The problem I had was I have the error 'connection reinitialized' during the query.

Comment: I just notice it only does this when I have more that 28 UNION SELECT... Any idea ?

Comment: How long is the query string for 28 or 29 records?